# Frosty water in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

How can I get water to look frosty?

I tried many ways, but no success yet:

- tried to change vertices of mesh
- tried to animate normal maps via script
- tried flowmap

But I'm not able to get a "Temple Run: kind of frosty water look.
I'd like something as in this image:

[image]

(Source: http://mobay.vn/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/329.png)

Any suggestions to solve this are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question a bit, and added the image directly into your question (as you don't have enough points to do this yourself yet). You could, if you want, further improve your question by telling us what the effects of these methods were - how they failed to create a "frosty water" look. Although I think your question is now good enough. Good luck and enjoy your stay!

Comment: thanks :) hopefully, someone will ans

Comment: Hi. As far as I can tell, this effect is as simple as slapping on a frosty looking texture. It doesn't like like there is anything special about the shader here. Maybe I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: thanks for rpl, could you post example?

Comment: I suggest trying in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com